# Use of if exists( ) in select statement

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I need to fetch a column from table2, if row exists, if not return it as null.

If i use ,**case when** it fetches only matched rows between table1 and table2.

If i use **left outer join** it fetches all the rows from table1 even though 
condition table1.code='A'

So i need ,some thing like this.

```
select table1.id,
if(row exist in table2 for query(table2.relation_type_id=55  and table1.id=table2.related_id)
then
return table2.parent_id
else
null
as parent_id,
table1.description,
from table1,table2 where table1.code='A'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.parent_id as parent_id 
FROM table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.related_id) 
WHERE table1.code = 'A';
```

EDIT based on comment :

```
  SELECT table1.id, sub.parent_id as parent_id 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (select parent_id,related_id from table2 where relation_type_id =55) sub ON (table1.id = sub.related_id) 
    WHERE table1.code = 'A';
```

Comment: i tried combination of case when and left outer join, it resulted all the rows from table1.i don't know how , but it fetched

Comment: And also, condition in joining table1 and table2 is table2.relation_type_id=55, then only we need to use table2 otherwise return null,thats why i am asking for **if exist** query

Comment: As suggested by navigator, you could filter only records required from table2 as a subquery, and solve as per solution provided above. Editing the answer. @navigator, your solution may not give all the ids in table1..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a sub-query?

```
select table1.id,
(select table2.parent_id from table2 where table2.relation_type_id=55 and table2.related_id=table1.id) parent_id,
table1.description,
from table1 where table1.code='A'
```